# Cloudant query slow speed using $or or $in

Tags: python, cloudant

I have an index setup for a field "userid". When I try and query with an and $or, I get a bad request.

```
query = cloudant.query.Query(db,selector={'$or':[{'userid': 35916}, {'userid': 11035}]},fields=['userid'])
```

Adding '_id' first works fine but it takes too long to get all docs first.

```
query = cloudant.query.Query(db,selector={'_id':{'$gt':0},'$or':[{'userid': 35916}, {'userid': 11035}]},fields=['userid'])
```

I get similar results when using $in instead of $or. What am I missing that can make this query quickly?

Comment: What index type are you using: `"json"` or `"text"`? This article has a good explanation of the differences: https://cloudant.com/blog/cloudant-query-grows-up-to-handle-ad-hoc-queries/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, I created a `"type": "json"` Cloudant Query index and followed the python-cloudant docs at http://python-cloudant.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html to write some simple test code. This snippet works for me:

```
import cloudant

client = cloudant.Cloudant("username", "password", account="account_name")
client.connect()
session = client.session()
db = client['testdb']

query1 = cloudant.query.Query(db,selector={'$or':[{'userid': 35916}, {'userid': 11035}]},fields=['_id', 'userid'])
#query2 = cloudant.query.Query(db,selector={'_id':{'$gt':0},'$or':[{'userid': 35916}, {'userid': 11035}]},fields=['_id', 'userid'])

for doc in query1.result:
    print doc

client.disconnect()
```

It returns:

```
{u'_id': u'266f9caae40012a04ce9223ccc67c8bd', u'userid': 35916}
{u'_id': u'5ff2cb156d16783492adb3eb8e2e0aec', u'userid': 11035}
```

Comment: Hm that's odd. I wonder if I changed something elsewhere that would raise the bad request error.

Comment: I still get the bad request error even when trying your code. Do you know what else might cause this? If I have multiple indexes set up with userid in them is that a problem?

Comment: What Cloudant cluster are you running on? I actually just reproduced _your_ error by replicating my database to a different cluster that I'm pretty sure is running an older version of Cloudant. I actually opened an issue for python-cloudant library [ https://github.com/cloudant/python-cloudant/issues/198#issuecomment-235283310 ].

Comment: Email cloudant support and ask to get on the sandbox cluster. Instructions here: https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/2016/03/18/cloudant-couchdb2dot0-sandbox/ That's as good of an immediate fix I can provide as of right now : / Good luck!

Comment: Aha! I am on Malort... I will try the sandbox and verify if it works for me. Thanks for looking into that I never would have thought to try it.

Comment: np. To be honest, I what you had _should_ work. So there's something funky going on, possibly with the version of Cloudant/CouchDB running on Malort. Anyway, thanks for the good question :D

Comment: I've now tested it with the same database on the sandbox cluster and can confirm that it works for me too with both $or or $in. However it is currently too slow for what I need- taking > 20 seconds to start printing docs (~500,000 docs in the database). I've created a userid index...

Comment: In case someone else has this problem, cloudant support recommended I create a text index and use the "use_index" parameter to query this index, which worked.

Answer (score 0):

My observation: $or and $in queries even complain about not finding an index even if querying on _id and using the _all_docs index. I think this boils down to a not very good query planning inside the db engine. I'm using CouchDB 2.0.